# different OpenMP output in different machine

Tags: openmp

When I m trying to run the following code in my system centos running virtually i am getting right output but when i am trying to run the same code on compact supercomputer "Param Shavak" I am getting incorrect output.... :(

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<omp.h>
int main()
{
  int p=1,s=1,ti
  #pragma omp parallel private(p,tid)shared(s)    
  {
    p=1;
    tid=omp_get_thread_num();    
    p=p+tid;    
    s=s+tid;    
    printf("Thread %d P=%d S=%d\n",tid,p,s);    
  }    
  return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Editing your question so we could read the code would help.  So would explaining what the differences in output are.  Notwithstanding all that you probably have a *data race* which is exposed only when you port it from one machine to another.  Have you tried running the code on varying numbers of threads on your system, and got the same results each time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your program runs correctly in one machine, it must be because it's actually not running in parallel in that machine.

Your program suffers from a race condition in the  `s=s+tid;` line of code. `s` is a shared variable, so several threads at the same time try to update it, which results in data loss.

You can fix the problem by turning that line of code into an atomic operation:

```
#pragma omp atomic
 s=s+tid;
```

That way only one thread at a time can read and update the variable `s`, and the race condition is no more.

In more complex programs you should use atomic operations or critical regions *only when necessary*, because you don't have parallelism in those regions and that hurts performance.

EDIT: As suggested by user High Performance Mark, I must remark that the program above is very inefficient because of the atomic operation. The proper way to do that kind of calculation (adding to the same variable in all iterations of a loop) is to implement a **reduction**.  OpenMP makes it easy by using the `reduction` clause:

```
#pragma omp reduction(operator : variables)
```

Try this version of your program, using reduction:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<omp.h>
int main()
{
     int p=1,s=1,tid;
     #pragma omp parallel reduction(+:s) private(p,tid)
     {
          p=1;
          tid=omp_get_thread_num();
          p=p+tid;
          s=s+tid;
          printf("Thread %d P=%d S=%d\n",tid,p,s);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

The following link explains critical sections, atomic operations and reduction in a more verbose way: http://www.lindonslog.com/programming/openmp/openmp-tutorial-critical-atomic-and-reduction/

Comment: If I could be bothered writing an answer I'd suggest using a *reduction* rather than, effectively, enforcing serial execution of the code.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark For a more general, practical case I'd suggest just that, of course. But the context suggested to me that the problem was a beginner's exercise. At that point I thought it better to give the simplest solution that guarantees correct execution, and let the OP learn about reduction later on.